# PHP: header alternative?

Tags: php, javascript

I wanted to know if the echoing the following would be a good alternative to using header("Location: index.html") without having to use output_buffering

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript>window.location = 'index.html';</script>";
```

There are times I would like to redirect possibly in a body, would the above work fine or is it worth turning on the output_buffering option and just user header()?

Comment: It will work as long as the user doesn't disable JS.

Comment: You could also use `<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com/">` if no-JS would be an issue.

Comment: output_buffering is a 'hack' for when your code is poorly structured.

Comment: If you aren't using header() you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I think the real problem is that you're deciding to redirect while you're in the middle of generating the content. Could you restructure your code to handle that type of logic before you start outputting anything?

Comment: It sounds daunting, but I strongly advise restructuring things so that you can perform a `header` redirect before outputting to the screen. MVC architecture works well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header()` defines the page the user is viewing. Using output buffering forces to ignore the previous output buffer, so it is not considered an efficient way to redirect. So, *here are my suggestions*:

1. If your **only target is to redirect**, then make sure you output nothing before `header` statement executes. In this case `header` is appropriate.
2. If you need to show your page and based on user interactivity need to redirect to the different page, use the JavaScript Redirection.

Answer (score 2):

Just use header(), it's the right way.

But you don't need to use output buffering. Build the "body" string and put it into a variable (don't echo stuff). Then use header if u have to. And in the last line of the script you echo the body variable (if u didn't redirect with header)

Comment: Or use a proper framework that deals with `Request` and `Response` objects. You shouldn't really ever have to worry about calling `header` yourself.

Comment: I didn't even think of putting the body into a string.  After reading everyones comments, I will use the header instead of js.  I should just eliminate having to redirect after the page starts loading.  Thanks everyone for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind that with header no output to the screen can be initiated otherwise header will not work, the JavaScript version will not work if JavaScript is turned off. Personally I'd say header is the safer option but I think it may be down to personal opinion!

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you want to avoid output buffering your idea would work.